# how can I make instances responsible to each-other

Tags: geometry-nodes, instances

I can generate pipe shapes from a collection fairly easily. My node setup only generates them on some points controlled but a colorRamp and a Noise texture. I've just now figured out how to use the pick index, and by replacing the randomValue node from my screenshot with an integer I can define which pipe I want to select; there are 5. Cap, Straight, Elbow, T, and Clover.

[image]

The points are not responsive to each-other in any way that I can find, however. I would like the points to obviously select the right pick index before spawning the instances, so that the pipes line up with each-other, or are capped with the Cap piece.

How can I detect if the other surrounding points in a Von-Nuemann neighborhood are selected and make change my integer pick index based on that?
like this:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a single integer number to describe all neighbors, by using the numbers bits (digits in binary representation) - I decided on a top-to-bottom, left-to-right ordering:

- leftmost (technically last) bit for a top connection,
- 2nd leftmost for left,
- 3rd leftmost for right,
- 4th leftmost (rightmost) for bottom.

[image]

The objects are sorted properly:

0. `0000` (binary `0000` is decimal `0`)
1. `0001` (binary `0001` is decimal `1`)
2. `0010` (binary `0010` is decimal `2`)
3. `0011` (binary `0011` is decimal `3`)
   etc.

Now use something like *Geometry Proximity* node, to check for neighbors of each point. Perhaps a more efficient way would be to delete geometry later and sample by indices if neighboring points are scheduled to be deleted or not, but I think this will be easier to understand:

[image]

Finally convert those four boolean values to one integer, by setting each integer's bit to the adequate boolean. Then pick instances using this integer as index:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: as I am just beginning to use geometry nodes, how may I store a variable to each instance? use capture attribute?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. This system seems like it is flexible to other polygons besides square as well, and has many uses