# How can I create a maze with an indented path in a mesh?

Tags: modeling, mesh

Sorry for being unclear the first time. I was in a rush and haven't noticed my silly mistakes (also english isn't my native lang.)I'll re-edit the question to be clear: How can I create a maze with an indented path in a mesh? I'd like to to re-create this image.

The method I tried was: 1. Imported an SVG maze I created in Illustrator. 2. Used the SVG to build my maze. 3. Used Boolean's  Difference to create the dents in the plane.

Unfortunately it didn’t look quite the same and the edges were too sharp. Since the mesh was a mess, I couldn’t bevel the edges, so I turned to you guys and amazed by all the solutions. Thank you for your help!! You're truly awesome. This was my first time ever asking here.

[image]

Comment: Would you mind at least sharing a few screenshots in your question to see what you're talking about? I have no idea what "punch an imported illustrator mazstrong texte" means and since I cannot see what you have so far I need a crystal ball to find out why you cannot fine tune the sharp edges - or even what fine tuning sharp edges is. Make them sharper? In some way more exact? Or bevel them so that they are not so sharp anymore?

Comment: Hello, do you need to use an existing svg or can you start from scratch?

Comment: I wonder what's the logic behind up-voting. Up-vote button tooltip says "This question shows research effort; it is useful and clear". It does show some effort, but as it is formed right now, is it truly useful and is it clear? The way I see it this question could definitely be useful for the community if it was formed clearly, but it's not clear at all, is it? "How do I model a maze with round track for a glass ball?" would be clear, but what does "I cant fine tune the sharp edges that created from the embedded maze. Any other way you think is better?" mean?..

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys Not everybody reads the tool tips, some people just upvote because they think it means "oh, good question, I would like to know the answer to that as well" or something like this (and other reasons surely, but I can't look in people's heads). And if we wanted to be very strict, the comments section is supposed to ask for clarification of certain aspects... so you asking for the logic behind up-voting is completely irrelevant to this specific question ;) But I get what you mean and this comment of me is completely irrelevant for the question, too.

Comment: I am just trying to understand to be honest. I down-vote quite a lot and before all the editing, I thought this question deserved a down-vote for sure and so I just wanted to understand the different perceptive and see if maybe I am missing something. With the title changed I retracted the down-vote. I still think the question is formulated very poorly, but I guess it is possible to understand it with the current title.

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys The problem is, the people up-voting might not even see your comment asking for understanding, and the one who asked the question will see your comment but might not be able to give you a reason either, since you only can see your question being up-voted but neither by whom nor why... so what I mean is you should rather ask for it on blender meta.

Comment: It's still sort of feedback to the question at the same time.

Comment: I upvoted, because the image is nice. BTW: [gorgeous maze generator](https://github.com/Gorgious56/MazeGenerator)

Comment: Sorry for being unclear! I was in a rush and haven't noticed my silly mistakes (also english isn't my native lang.) I'll try to be clear now:

All I wanted to know is how to re-create this image. 
The method I tried was:
1. Importing an SVG maze I created
2. Used a Boolean modifier on a plane 

Unfortunately it didn’t look quite the same and the edges were too sharp.
Since the mesh was a mess, I couldn’t bevel the edges, so I turned to you guys and amazed by all the solutions. Thank you for your help!!

Comment: I upvoted it as it was formulated at the beginning because even though you're right, it was very badly formulated, I decided to translate it as "how to do that", and how to do that seemed interesting to me   ;)

Comment: Guys it's my first time here and it was a typo because I was rushing. I re-framed the question. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have Illustrator you can save as SVG and import into Blender ...

[image]

Under *Curve properties > Geometry* > **Bevel** choose type **Profile** and adjust curvature ...

[image]

*Convert to Mesh*  and use *Loop Tool* addon > **Bridge** to fill the gaps ...

[image]

Under *Object Data Properties* > *Normal* > enable **Auto Smooth** ...

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for the help!! Appreciated

Answer (score 7):

Since I haven't used geo-bool in a while… [I have no idea if it won't fail miserably while starting to write this answer]

Create a subdivided plane. Too little and the maze is too easy, too much and boolean murders you.

Enable proportional editing, select middle vertex, <kbd>G</kbd>, <kbd>Z</kbd> to move it up, $\color{#888}{█}\color{green}⬇\color{#888}{█}$ *mouse wheel down* to increase the range by a lot (so near vertices aren't visibly biased), move your mouse to scramble heights.

[image]

Then in <kbd>Numpad 7</kbd> *Top Orthographic View* click on the maze start, and <kbd>✲ Ctrl</kbd>-click creatively to reach the maze end. **Avoid boundary edges.** You could <kbd>2</kbd> and click to select one edge on boundary, then <kbd>⬆ Shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>, <kbd>A</kbd> "Amount of Faces Around an Edge", <kbd>H</kbd> to hide temporarily, but as you can see below, I'm too skillful to need this step:

[image]

Assign selection to a vertex group. Then <kbd>A</kbd> select all, <kbd>.</kbd>, <kbd>D</kbd> switch to 3D cursor orientation, <kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>0</kbd> Flatten everything back.

Add Geometry Nodes:

[image]

[image]

Name this node tree e.g. "Labyrinth Generator", create a new tree and insert it as a custom group. Now convert the labyrinth to curve, fillet it, convert to mesh giving it thickness.

I'll spare you trying to use Boolean, it doesn't work and takes a lot of time:

[image]

Time for Plan B: spawn a dense grid, and shrinkwrap (raycast) on the pipes. Either use a switch in case of misses to also move up to a 0 level, or join another grid with the pipes that will make sure all rays are stopped:

[image]

Smooth:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Unmuting the "Transform" node, reducing grid resolution to 500×500, increasing smoothing to 15 iterations, and maximum (clamped) fillet radius:

[image]

[image]

For better topology and much faster generation, consider replacing the shrinkwrapping with this technique:

[how can I make instances responsible to each-other](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/286675/60486)

Comment: That's crazy!  It's def advanced for me but I must try it. Appreciate the help

Answer (score 6):

A quick method that will create something close to what you want, subdivide a plane, select some faces:

[image]

Inset (<kbd>i</kbd>) and move down:

[image]

Bevel the edges in order to sharpen them (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Edge Crease*):

[image]

Give it a *Subdivision Surface* modifier and shade smooth (now you can begin to create some edge loops with the knife in order to change the shapes):

[image]

Comment: Quick, but the main issue with this technique is that corner radius is the same on outer-inner side (ends are not circular, but that is a cosmetic) ... https://imgur.com/KpY9Q3S

Comment: I agree, it's far from perfect, it needs some adjustements

Comment: Thanks for your help! I appreciate this.