# De-overlap geometry in simulation nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, simulation-nodes

How to extrude only non-overlapping faces in simulation nodes with random probability, or remove the duplicated faces?

The overlapping geometry is causing black on Cycles render.

| Nodes | Material view | Cycles render |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [image: nodes] | [image: solid] | [image: cycles render] |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand\vec[1]{\begin{bmatrix}#1\end{bmatrix}}$

Since it's just voxels, snapped to grid, instead of extruding you could just spawn vertices, then merge by distance to remove doubles. You could also make the voxels aware of their surroundings, like I do here:

[how can I make instances responsible to each-other](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/286664/60486)

Here's a simple solution to your problem:

[image]

The ColorRamp contains 6 evenly spaced colors:

- $\vec{0\\0.5\\0.5}×\vec{2\\2\\2}+\vec{-1\\-1\\-1}=\vec{-1\\0\\0}$ go **left**
- $\vec{1\\0.5\\0.5}×\vec{2\\2\\2}+\vec{-1\\-1\\-1}=\vec{+1\\0\\0}$ go **right**
- $\vec{0.5\\0\\0.5}×\vec{2\\2\\2}+\vec{-1\\-1\\-1}=\vec{0\\-1\\0}$ go **backwards**
- $\vec{0.5\\1\\0.5}×\vec{2\\2\\2}+\vec{-1\\-1\\-1}=\vec{0\\+1\\0}$ go **forwards**
- $\vec{0.5\\0.5\\0}×\vec{2\\2\\2}+\vec{-1\\-1\\-1}=\vec{0\\0\\-1}$ go **down**
- $\vec{0.5\\0.5\\0}×\vec{2\\2\\2}+\vec{-1\\-1\\-1}=\vec{0\\0\\+1}$ go **up**

There's also an integer *Counter* attribute that keeps track of how many times a vertex **tried** to spawn another vertex. I say *"tried"*, because it's possible it wasn't a new vertex and just got merged with an old one. And to improve performance I stop trying to spawn more vertices from a vertex that already tried twice.

The probability maybe should decrease based on the size of the geometry, but it was supposed to be a minimal example.

[image]

If that doesn't render well in Cycles, you could realize instances and merge by instance or use the link at the beginning to figure out instances depending on their surroundings (basically square 3D pipe segments).

[image]