# Geometry Nodes: Place different objects dependend on location with vertex color

Tags: objects, geometry-nodes, color

I edited my question to hopefully make it more clear and easy to answer:

What is my goal? I want something similar to this in blender: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RfyXNhOnQQg&t=3m2s

My starting point is a plane where I delete faces based on vertex color to "paint" geometry. So far so good.
Then I select the faces in the corner and edge of the plane, so give them a different material.
[image: Starting point]

But now here is my problem: I want every face at edge and corner have a different material, based at which direction is outside. For example for the orange corner, the outside is +Y/-X. But how do I get this attribute and select with it?
[image: Desired result]

If it's not possible with this method, I'm open for other ideas. My goal is just to automatically place a fitting texture to corners and edges to save a lot of time in contrast by placing every cube/texture by hand.

Thanks in advance for every help!

Comment: Are your corner tiles rotations of one another, or separate entities?

Comment: Best case separate entities, but rotation could work too.

Comment: Possibly related: [how can I make instances responsible to each-other](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/286664/60486)

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady thanks, will look into it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my attempt:

[image]

Inside node group:

[image]

The idea is to look at 4 edges of faces and set a color based on there this edge is located around face center.

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot, looks convenient. Unfortunately I couldn't get it to work if I put my vertex paint method in front to delete faces depending on where I paint. Seems that the indices get messed up.

Comment: you should plug mesh data into node groups after removing vertices

Comment: Ah, I had something else wrong, works now! I think that answers my initial question. But maybe I can get it a bit further: Is it also possible to select the inner corner faces (black marked)? https://imgur.com/a/qYq2exN

Comment: @Trick it's feasible, but more complicated. It should get vertices of 4 corners and check how many face corners are connected to each vertex. If it is 4,4,4,3 it should be that face.

Comment: I understand the logic behind that and tried it several ways, but I have no idea how to archieve that so that I can isolate the wanted faces. The whole attribute and index thing is not very intuitive for me.

Comment: you can use separate geometry node to separate faces by compare node result. You can ask another question if you faced problems with that