# Geometry Nodes - Optimizing mesh instancing on a patchy grid

Tags: geometry-nodes, instances, point-clouds

I have this generated selection of points that I'm instancing meshes onto, they are in a grid pattern but not all spaces on the grid contain a point.
What I want to ask is if it's possible to cycle through the points and find which have enough neighbors to merge together and then use the new point position for instancing other larger, pre-made meshes to fill the space. Image attached for clarity on what I mean. [image]

[image]

Comment: if something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/35wZt.png . Not larger instances but ngons. Is it interesting for what you want?

Comment: Thanks but I'm afraid not.  Sorry if I wasn't clear, I want to combine some of the points where there are more squares instanced, so I can instead instance larger squares.  For example, there are several spots where we could replace 9 smaller squares with 1 larger 3x3 one.

Comment: I think this is a good starting point: [how can I make instances responsible to each-other](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/286664/60486)

Comment: Thanks! That looks promising :)